# Beautiful soup cannot find any element

Tags: python-3.x

I am just starting out with web scraping. I am having trouble with beautiful soup. I have tried changing the div class to other classes as well but it always returns []. Here is my code.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/MuhIsmail/Downloads/cd79/chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match/live-scores"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(4)
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
scores = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-xs-9 col-lg-9 dis-inline')
print(scores)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match/live-scores")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


for item in soup.select("a.cb-mat-mnu-itm:nth-child(5)"):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
MLR vs SYS - SYS Won
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning `[]` because there are no elements on the page with that class.

If you open your browser console and do a simple

```
document.getElementsByClassName('col-xs-9 col-lg-9 dis-inline')
```

it will return no results.

I tried this as well:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-match/live-scores"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
scores = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'col-xs-9 col-lg-9 dis-inline'})
print(scores)
```

Comment: On the actual page..if you see "MLR vs SYS...Sydney sixers won by 6 wickets" ...can you tell me the div id of that?

Comment: try 
   `scores = soup.find('a', {'class':'cb-mat-mnu-itm cb-ovr-flo'}).get_text()`